# What happened with RawValue property on ValueProviderResult on asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am moving an `IModelBinder` to asp.net core but `ValueProviderResult` does not have a `RawValue`. What is the equivalent on asp.net core. Is `FirstValue` a good replacement?

Comment: Yup! `FirstValue` is a good replacement for `RawValue`.